# Windows batch script: Manual power up vs Wake on Lan (WOL)

Tags: windows, batch, script, batch-file, wake-on-lan

OK, I have a (win 7) desktop computer with WOL set up so I can turn it on remotely, it works fine. Next thing, on this computer I have a batch script, which runs at startup and starts various apps, also works well:) But sometimes, when I am physically present at the computer, I power it up manually - and I need complete different set of apps.. so I must typically close all apps started by script and then execute another, which is a bit.. low tech:)

**Question is:** Can we tell in which way was the computer powered on - manually or WOL, in a batch script?

I would imagine it like this:

```
IF %wolpowerstatus% equ 1 (
   Echo Computer powered up by WOL
   :: spam ugly dark commandline apps all over desktop
) ELSE ( 
   Echo Computer powered up by the user
   :: run those pretty apps with gui
)
```

.

**Update:**
I were pointed to hopefully right direction by mnmnc. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031755/check-if-computer-is-activated-through-wake-on-lan) seem to offer a solution. Unfortunately I cannot confirm it to work as I am completely untouched by Powershell yet :)

Comment: If there is a way to do this it must be via Powershell. You can try to access the Event logs with Powershell. I'm not sure but in the system event log there might be a indication if the PC was booted by a network card.

Comment: Or - maybe it would be actually easier not to check for WOL events but to check if there is a connection established on port 3389 - RDP connection which you would most probably use after WOL. That could be done in batch and powershell would not be needed. `netstat -an | FIND "ESTABLISHED" | FIND ":3389"`

Comment: I don't know how to do it. But if you have a server wich performs the WoL you could program some kind of Web Service there that tells the computer if it has been waken up from there.

Comment: Wait, what is the point of your update. To say it is a solution to your problem or that you expect to go away, learn something, then report back?

Comment: TY for ideas, just checked and there is no connection on 3389. There is only one connection with server on 445 and that is here also after manual start. Server not really talks to the desktop after it wakes it up. With the web service.. I can imagine that too, when everything else fails.

Comment: Dave Rook: Exactly, I have to get familiar with powershell first, then I can report back with more info. Users with same problem can follow the link in update for now.